# How can I interpret the circuit of the voltage probe with cable between the probe body and the compensation box?

Tags: voltage-divider, transmission-line

Let's take a look at the voltage probe circuit without the cable between the probe body and the compensation box.
[image]

This circuit is a typical RC voltage divider and the following relation holds; $${R_P} = \beta {R_{OSC}},{\rm{ }}{{\rm{C}}_P} = \frac{1}{\beta }C'
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHb5MDXbpmVaibaieYlf9irVe
% eu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVk
% FHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabiGaci
% aacaqabeaadaqaaqaafaGcbaGaamOuamaaBaaaleaacaWGqbaabeaa
% kiabg2da9iabek7aIjaadkfadaWgaaWcbaGaam4taiaadofacaWGdb
% aabeaakiaacYcacaqGGaGaae4qamaaBaaaleaacaWGqbaabeaakiab
% g2da9maalaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiabek7aIbaacaWGdbGaai4jaaaa!5081!
$$ where $$C' = \left( {{C_C} + {C_{OSC}}} \right)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHb5MDXbpmVaibaieYlf9irVe
% eu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVk
% FHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabiGaci
% aacaqabeaadaqaaqaafaGcbaGaam4qaiaacEcacqGH9aqpdaqadaqa
% aiaadoeadaWgaaWcbaGaam4qaaqabaGccqGHRaWkcaWGdbWaaSbaaS
% qaaiaad+eacaWGtbGaam4qaaqabaaakiaawIcacaGLPaaaaaa!4A8A!
$$ is the equivalent capacitance of the compensation box and the oscilloscope and $$\beta  = \frac{{1 - \alpha }}{\alpha },{\rm{ }}\frac{{{V_{out}}}}{{{V_{in}}}} = \alpha
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHb5MDXbpmVaibaieYlf9irVe
% eu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVk
% FHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabiGaci
% aacaqabeaadaqaaqaafaGcbaGaeqOSdiMaeyypa0ZaaSaaaeaacaaI
% XaGaeyOeI0IaeqySdegabaGaeqySdegaaiaacYcacaqGGaWaaSaaae
% aacaWGwbWaaSbaaSqaaiaad+gacaWG1bGaamiDaaqabaaakeaacaWG
% wbWaaSbaaSqaaiaadMgacaWGUbaabeaaaaGccqGH9aqpcqaHXoqyca
% GGUaaaaa!53AF!
$$

So far so good. However, **what about the voltage probe with the cable?**

[image]

In this case, there is the cable between the probe body and the compensation box and the cable should be treated as a transmission line in general case. So, ***Zin*, the equivalent impedance from the cable, through the compensation box, to the oscilloscope is such that $${R_P} = \beta {R_{in}},{\rm{ }}{{\rm{C}}_P} = \frac{1}{\beta }{C_{in}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbWexLMBbXgBd9gzLbvyNv2CaeHb5MDXbpmVaibaieYlf9irVe
% eu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-JfrVk
% FHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabiGaci
% aacaqabeaadaqaaqaafaGcbaGaamOuamaaBaaaleaacaWGqbaabeaa
% kiabg2da9iabek7aIjaadkfadaWgaaWcbaGaamyAaiaad6gaaeqaaO
% GaaiilaiaabccacaqGdbWaaSbaaSqaaiaadcfaaeqaaOGaeyypa0Za
% aSaaaeaacaaIXaaabaGaeqOSdigaaiaadoeadaWgaaWcbaGaamyAai
% aad6gaaeqaaaaa!5150!
$$ where Rin and Cin in parellel connection which equivalent impedance is Zin?**

Comment: There is a big difference in cost and complexity of a 20MHz probe and a 200MHz probe due to dielectric constant of coax and capacitance reducing with rising f.  Both coax impedance and capacitance changes need higher order RLC compensation.  Also Probe coax tends to be higher than 50 Ohms and much less than 10pF /ft rather than typical 30pF/ft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most straightforward to just treat the cable as a parallel capacitance rather than a terminated line.  The capacitance of coax will be in the range 20-30pF/ft.
That is a about 90pF for a 3 feet cable.  This will appear in parallel with Cc. Cp will need to be correspondingly larger to compensate the network.

In reality the cable is not made as a normal coax, it often uses a very fine gauge resistance wire as the centre conductor to reduce the capacitance and also to minimize resonances.

Also in real scope probes intended to have 100 MHz of bandwidth or more there will be  number of other small inductors and capacitors to equalize the response at high frequencies.

This is an old but very good document from Tektronix Circuit Concepts series describing scope probe circuits. [Oscilloscope Probe Circuits](http://www.davmar.org/TE/TekConcepts/TekProbeCircuits.pdf)

EDIT:

At low frequencies where the wavelength is large compared to the length of the cable the cable can be treated as a lumped element model.

With high system impedances and moderate frequencies the inductance component can ignored. Typically real scope probed will use resistance wire as the center conductor to minimize any resonances caused by the cable inductance.

Comment: Thanks for giving me some comments. Hm...the coax or any other cable in a real oscilloscope probe is treated as a parallel capacitance, rather than the transmission line... **What about inductance of the cable? Is it normally small enough so that it is ignored?** And I think your picture is so called a lumped element model. **What is the criterion telling us when we should treat the cable as the transmission line or the lumped element model?**

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer to give me the additional information. So I guess that the probe works well if the signal wavelength is much longer than the cable length so that the analysis by the transmission line theory is not necessarily taken into account. Hm...what happens if the wavelength is comparable to the cable length? For example, our 200 MHz bandwidth Tektronics voltage probe looks having the cable length of ~ 2 m. However, the wavelength at 200 MHz is just 1.5 m! So...the probe doesn't work well at this frequency?

Comment: With probes such as you describe the designer will have to have done various things to avoid transmission line effects - using resistance wire is one such change they will also put various inductances/capacitance networks at the probe and scope end to equalize the response.  Th probe will not be high impedance at high frequencies - did you look at the link I included, such as fig 2-18?